# Comparação de arrays ou melhor método para adicionar novos elementos

Tags: jquery, json, array

tenho uma webservice em json que me retorna as últimas pessoas que passaram em um determinado local.

Dito isto fiz o seguinte:

- Apenas peço para a api sempre as informações da última pessoa a passar no local.
- Criei em minha pagina in `setInterval` de 1s para ler esta api e fazer um `prepend` com as informações deste json na tela dentro de uma div.

Feito isto reparei que há um problema. Quando varias pessoas passam em menos de 1s eu perco ou melhor eu pulo a exibição de algumas pessoas na tela.

Defini por padrão com que a api me devolvesse sempre as ultimas 9 pessoas
dai preciso comparar os ids dos box que ja estão na tela com os ids que vem do json e saber quais IDs não tem na tela para que eu possa incluir no prepend essas pessoas. Alguém poderia me auxiliar nessa questão de saber quais ids existem em um array 1 que não existem no array 2 ?

---

Fiz um código de acordo com a ajuda abaixo mas ele esta retornando vasio

```
setInterval(function() {    
    var api = [],tela = [];
    $(".cardface").each(function(){
        tela.push($(this).attr('idimg'));
    });

    $.getJSON('<?php url(); ?>/rtffeed', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key,val){
            api.push(val.id_imagens);
        });        
    });


    var adicionar = $(api).not(tela).get();

    console.log(adicionar);

}, 1000);
```

sendo que se eu fizer

```
console.log(tela);
```

ele retorna 
`{317,318}`
e c eu fizer

```
console.log(api);
```

ele retorna `{322,321,319,318,317,316,315,314,313}`

entao o adicionar deveria ser `{322,321,319,316,315,314,313}`

mas ele esta voltando em branco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
tela, api, adicionar nesta ordem

Comment: Mas os ids vem em formato array? Coloca o formato do retorno dos ids.

Comment: vao ta em array eu ja formatei tenho 2 arrays um com a lista dos ids das pessoas q ja tem na tela e o outro com a lista das ultimas 9 pessoas que passaram no local

Comment: var json = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], tela = [4,2];

Comment: seria assim se fosse setado na mao

Answer (score 1):

Pose fazer assim se quiser, testando se um elemento não existe no outro:

```js
var json = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];           // elementos à adicionar
var tela = [4,2];                         // elementos já adicionados

var adicionar = $(json).not(tela).get();  // retorna os que não derão match

console.log(String(adicionar));           // Resultado em forma de String
console.log(adicionar);                   // Resultado em forma de Array
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: da uma olhada fiz um update no meu post com o codigo como ficou mas sem funcionar.

Comment: Mas vc está dando o console.log(api , tela) onde Jasar? Tem que dar fora das funções **each** para ver se os arrays estão mesmo sendo preenchidos.

Comment: estao sim e estava dando console.log no meio do cod e estava retornando valores como no print